Why does slice after trimming to 0 element still have elements?
I have this code on Golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s = s[:0]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:4]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}

Why in line "s = s[:4]" there are yet elements in slice? If before it I sliced it to 0 index
And when I do this (cut to 0 index twice), then I get error
func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    //printSlice(s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s = s[:0]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    //printSlice(s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:0]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    //printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    //printSlice(s)
}

panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
Why in this case I get error?

You changed the code commented as "extend its length" to not extend its length, hence the next slice is invalid. Read the accompanying text in that page of the tour of Go, and see Slice Expressions

Slice operations do not change the underlying array in any way. https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro has some diagrams that may help build your mental model.

Welcome, with Slices you've discovered one of the big traps on Go. As addition to the other comments another warning: append can modfiy the underlying slice. (The other big trap are nil checks on typed interfaces. And so much for the goal of creating an idiomatic, easy-to-understand language.)

Perhaps it's easier to understand when you write it that way:
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    fmt.Printf("s len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)

    s1 := s[:0]
    fmt.Printf("s1 len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s1), cap(s1), s1)

    s2 := s1[:4]
    fmt.Printf("s2 len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s2), cap(s2), s2)

    s3 := s2[2:]
    fmt.Printf("s3 len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s3), cap(s3), s3)

    s3[0] = 6

    fmt.Printf("s len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    fmt.Printf("s1 len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s1), cap(s1), s1)
    fmt.Printf("s2 len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s2), cap(s2), s2)
    fmt.Printf("s3 len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s3), cap(s3), s3)
}

You're redefining a view on the same underlying array. Whether you reassign the variable or use different variables makes no difference.
The error you get in the slice expression s1[2:] for a zero length slice s1 is because this implicitly means s1[2:0] (a missing high index defaults to the length of the sliced operand), which violates “low <= high.”
Otherwise, the links from JimB and Peter in the comments are good resources to learn more.
